# Formatting multiple drives on AIX

Tags: linux, aix, ibm-server

I originally got help here to figure out how to remove multiple drives from a list.

I now would like to try and use that same sort of code to format multiple drives with a loop.

```
for i in `lsdev -Cc disk |grep Defined|awk '{print $1}'`; do rmdev -dl $i; done
```

This code gets rid of all my defined hard drives.

I would like to know if its possible to use this to format drives in AIX. I would also like to note that my OS disk HDISK0 is Available, but I do not want to wipe this drive.

```
for i in `lsdev -Cc disk |grep Available|
```

I found this code online, but am not sure as to what it does.

```
for disk in $(lspv | awk '{print $1}') ; do
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/r${disk} bs=1024 count=10
echo $disk wiped
done
```

This photo is what it would normally look like. I have to go line by line selecting each drives and then telling the system to wipe the drive. I also have to open up a new terminal window for each drive. Which can be up to 40+ at a time.

Answer (score 1):

What the code does is it writes "zero" blocks over the first 10 mb of the disk, which effectively overwrites it.

The code below will take all the disks on your system except ones marked "rootvg" (i.e. your OS disks) and overwrite them.

```
    for disk in $(lspv | grep -v rootvg | awk '{print $1}') ; do
    dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/r${disk} bs=1024 count=10
    echo $disk wiped
    done
```

Good luck and be careful.

David.

Comment: I havent checked this in forever. Thanks for the response. Will this solution allow me to see those drives that ran data errors. The values of how many it recovered and how many it had?

Comment: No, it will do none of those things unless you build that into the script. I'm not sure what you mean by "ran data errors". If there is a hardware error, it should be caught by the o/s in errpt. If there are errors with data that is not related to hardware, doing the disk wipe with "dd" will make it irrelevant. How many disks you processed or wiped can be built in to the script easily with a pipe to "wc -l". If you are looking for further help, please be more specific with your situation and I'll try to assist.